# Background Image in slanted and bordered Div

Tags: html, css, background-image, border, skew

I'm currently experimenting around with various, more 'unique' looking designs for websites. My latest experiment is a slanted box next to a text – this is difficult to explain in words so I've provided a photoshopped image as well as a jsFiddle with what I managed to do so far:

What it should look like:
[image]

What it currently looks like: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5wdqus7/)

```
.row {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    border-top: 1px blue solid;
    border-bottom: 1px blue solid;
}
    .text {
        float: left;
        width: 70%;
        height: 590px;
        padding: 0px 10px;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .slanted {
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
        height: 590px;
        border-left: 10px blue solid;
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-25deg);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
        .picture {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
            background-image: url("http://www.theheritagehotel.com/upload/sequencer_images/gym-2.jpg");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            transform:skewX(25deg);
            -ms-transform:skewX(25deg);
            -webkit-transform:skewX(25deg);
        }
```

Am I on the right path here or how should I best approach this kind of design? I've found many very similiar questions, but none of them seemed to work for this particular design choice.

Comment: Not meaning to discourage you are anything, but the easiest route would just be to use an image, then position it as a background image

Comment: yes, position it as a background and maybe slide in a div on hover? be creative. Images like that are generally best left static.

Comment: Yeah it would definitely be the easiest route to just create the image as an already cropped picture with a slanted white part of it cut out – it'll probably be the way I'll go if there is no other proper way to go about it.

For a variety of reasons (responsive websites, easy switching of images without editing them first, cleaner design) I'd still like to explore other options, harder route or not. Still, thank you very much for the confirmation of what seems like the easiest route to take, Jacob and Gothburz!